# Invalid Syntax for CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

what in the world could be wrong, the syntax looks fine:

```
With photos(PhotoID, MemberID) as
(
    select  photoID,
            memberID
    from MemberPhotos
)
select PhotoID, MemberID from photos
```

Comment: What's the error? Which line is the error on?

Answer (score 3):

If the `CTE` follows from another query, you should add a `semi-colon` before the `WITH` keyword.

```
;With photos(PhotoID, MemberID) as
(
    select  photoID,
            memberID
    from MemberPhotos
)
select PhotoID, MemberID from photos
```